# What kind of mouse has best performance to use with a Mac?

Tags: usb, bluetooth, mouse

I recently got a Mac upgrade to a new MacBook Air (10.14.6), which only has two new small USB-C connections. I therefore bought a USB-C to old USB adaptor to be able to connect my harddrives, USB sticks and the wireless mouse (working with a USB receiver).

But now it turns out that the mouse input is lagging a LOT compared to the old Mac (where I could use the USB receiver directly in a USB post). Also the mousepad itself works perfectly normal.

The lag is not only very disturbing when playing games (such as minecraft), but also with normal operations (finding and clicking on an app, dragging files etc). The lag is clearly a result of the USB C adaptor.

So how to avoid this problem best? Should I

1. buy a new wireless mouse with USB-C receiver
2. buy a bluetooth mouse
3. buy a wired USB-C mouse?

Which is the best option to maximally reduce any lag?

Comment: Buy an Apple mouse.  They work well with Macs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have arrived at the wrong conclusion. A USB-C to USB-A adapter cannot introduce lag on your mouse. It’s only a mechanical adapter from one type of plug to another - there’s nothing changed in the actual electric signal.

I would look at:

1) ensuring your have the correct driver

2) ensure that there are no sources of noise near the wireless adapter (try disabling WiFi, Bluetooth etc on the Mac to see if it is disturbed by those)

3) that the actual wireless antenna for the mouse is placed near the mouse

Comment: How can I check that the driver is correct? Option (2) can be ruled out as there is no change in the environment - only the MAC has changed (and the adaptor). Point (3) is a bit hard as I am right handed and the USB-C plugs are on the left side.

Comment: The easiest way is to reinstall the driver. Regarding (2) your answer does not make sense - if you have replaced the computer then you have definitely changed the environment. (3) You could pretend to be left handed for a few minutes to check if it works - then buy an extension cable if it does. Logitech mice are notorious for having short reach unless you use the supplied extra extension cable.

Comment: I tried (3) again with a USB extension; now it seems to work much better! But with the old Mac the receiver was also on the left side! Regarding the environment change using a newer mac: I agree, the new mac could be slower!

Comment: It doesn’t have anything to do with the Mac being “slow” - that is not the cause of the lagging. The problem is that the radio signal from the mouse to the adapter is weak - this is a known problem with for example Logitech mice. They mention it in the accompanying manual - the recommendation is to use the included extension cable to get the receiver closer to the mouse. The environment change I’m talking about is the RF environment. I.e. as the signal is very weak, just having a bit more metal in some specific place is enough to trigger retransmissions of the mouse data - which is the lag!